# Can't convert HashWithIndifferentAccess to String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a hash being posted to my Rails app that looks like this:

```
{"signed_request"=>"...",
 "buyer"=>"1064897036",
 "receiver"=>"1064897036",
 "order_id"=>"224539980951036",
 "method"=>"payments_get_items",
 "test_mode"=>"1",
 "order_info"=>{"description"=>"None",
 "image_url"=>"",
 "price"=>"1",
 "product_url"=>"",
 "title"=>"Premium Membership"}}
```

I'm borrowing some code to parse this and post the appropriate response back. First, I parse the signed request, which is working fine, then I build the order info to send it back to the server. That's where the trouble is starting, it seems:

```
 ...
        elsif method == 'payments_get_items'

                  order_info = params[:order_info]

                  item = JSON.parse(order_info)
              item['price'] = item['price'].to_i

              # for url fields, if not prefixed by http://, prefix them
              url_key = [ 'product_url', 'image_url' ]
              url_key.each do |key|
                if item[key][0..6] != 'http://'
                  item[key] = "http://#{item[key]}"
                end
              end

 # if payload['test_mode']
              if request.params['test_mode']
                update_keys = ['title', 'description']
                update_keys.each do |key|
                    item[key] = '[Test Mode] ' + item[key]
                end
              end

              data['content'] = [item]  
            end

            data['method'] = method

            render :json => data
          end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
can't convert ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String
```

It's being caused by this line:

```
  item = JSON.parse(order_info)
```

I'm not sure what it means at all. The alternative, I guess ... is that I can get the server to pass just an item number, then I can query the database and pull out the info myself as JSON, instead of trying to parse the hash, but I'd like to make this work if I can. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no JSON that needs to be parsed here. Your params hash is simply a nested hash so all you need to do to access the nested `:order_info` data is `item = params[:order_info]`